# Wrong output when searching with indexOf

Tags: java

```
 int locsPlusLast = locsPlus.get(locsPlus.size()-1);
        System.out.println(locsPlusLast);
          int index = checkScanning.indexOf('(',locsPlusLast);
             while(index>=0){
                   index = checkScanning.indexOf('(',locsPlusLast+1);
                 System.out.println(index);
         }
```

The **checkScanning** is scanner input.

I want only to output the position of (,but it outputs the postition of ) two , why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I misunderstood your question.
Try this:

```
private static void positionOf(char target, String query) {

    int position = 0;
    int result = 0;

    while(-1 != (result = query.indexOf(target, position))){

        System.out.println(result);
        position = result +1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf inside while loop and incrementing the counter to find out the number of
occurences of a single specified character in a string. You don't need a while loop here. [indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29) returns the index.

```
int pos = str.indexOf('(');
while(pos  >= 0) {
 System.out.println(pos);
 pos = str.indexOf('(', pos +1);
}
```

Comment: Butineed a loop i'm searching the position of multiple (

Comment: I see, totally misinterpreted your question. Check the updated post.

Comment: Can you paste the checkScanning and locsPlusLast. Please provide more description on your question as well.

Comment: Once again, what is locPlus..please paste it's content. And when you say Two, do you mean Too?

Comment: With the locsPlus, for example i'm searching the character a from the scanner,but the locsPlus get's the last "a" charcter

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to find the position of the char '(' ?
The second argument to API indexOf() is the starting index, the search is performed after this index.

It would be helpful if you provide the value of checkScanning and the output of your query.

### API:

```
indexOf(String str, int fromIndex) 
// Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified
// substring, starting at the specified index.
```

### Example:

```
String str = "Test(Bracket)(position)";
System.out.println("Position: "+ str.indexOf('(',1));
System.out.println("Position: "+ str.indexOf('(',5));
```

### Output:

```
Position: 4
Position: 13
```